# Add dynamic elements with jquery when I choose element from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have list of elements and when I choose element from list, "value" from code below are changing.

```
    <div class="drop-down-cont zi-5 fleft">
          <input class="dd-input" id="packaging_item_packaging_name" name="packaging_item[packaging_name]" title="Packaging Type" type="hidden" value="PX">
          <a class="drop-down-link item-qnt" href="#" id="packaging_item_packaging_name_link">Pallet</a>
          <div class="drop-down pic" style="visibility: visible; ">
            <div class="blue-tarr"></div>
            <div class="drop-down-list-cont w400">
              <div class="drop-down-list first pt-cases w100p" id="cases_results_"><ul class="w100p">
  
<li id="PX" class="selected">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Pallet</a>
</li>
<li id="PB">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Pallet Box</a>
</li>
<li id="PLP">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Peel pack</a>
</li>
    
</ul>



</div>
              <div class="pic-cont h100p"><img alt="Package Image" src="/images/pi_new/32.jpg?1312107854"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="remark">
A platform used to hold or transport unit loads. 

</div>
            <a class="submit-btn2 pt-choose-btn-" href="javascript:void(0)" id="pack_apply">Apply</a>
          </div>
        </div>

<table id="pallet_table" style="display:none;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stacking factor:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="w44" id="packaging_item_stacking_factor" name="packaging_item[stacking_factor]" size="30" type="text" value="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to show table when I choose 'value' to 'PX' and execute this script,

```
if ($('.dd-input').attr('value') == 'PX') {
    $('#pallet_table').show();}
```

but this doesn't work dynamically. How I can handle this event then I change value from 'smth' to 'PX'

Comment: I can't see your list in the html you've pasted. What event do you want to trigger?

Comment: This doesn't matter. It's drop-down list from other file, but when I choose some element this change value in <input class="dd-input" name="packaging_item[packaging_name]" title="Packaging Type" type="hidden" value="smth">

Comment: @MikhailAleksandrovi4: This does matter, you are not specific enough. If you are able to bind the event to the dropdown list, it would be easier and cleaner to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uur9A/)):

```
jQuery('.dd-input').bind('change', function(){
    if (jQuery(this).val() == 'PX'){
        // do here whatever you need
        $('#pallet_table').show();
    }
});
```

I do not see however, how you would like the user to change the value of this field (in your code the field is hidden). If this is done through a different script, maybe the current approach is not the best one and you should call some function explicitly instead of doing it when the value is changed?

Comment: This code work's fine http://jsfiddle.net/Uur9A/16/ , but in my context, this solution doesn't work. I have form, where this event must execute before submit

Comment: @MikhailAleksandrovi4: There are many possibilities to execute code before something is submitted - you can intercept `submit` event, you can even [prefilter AJAX calls](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/). Really, saying " _this can not be done_ " is most of the time a result of underestimating possible solutions.

Comment: yes I was able to use the previous submit, where I choose from the list of elements